# How to download a ZIP folder from a remote FTP Server using SAS

Tags: ftp, sas

I am trying to execute code in SAS that help streamline my FTP operation. Here are the steps that I'm trying to complete:

1. Connect to FTP Server
2. Scan all .zip folders for a specific name format
3. Copy all folders that have that format to my Local machine

Thus far I seem to have managed to connect to the FTP Server, but I'm unsure about the rest.
Here is my code:

```
filename rmt ftp 'foo.csv.zip' host='ftp.bar.com' 
user='FooUser' pass='BarPass'
cd='/' recfm=s debug;

FILENAME lcl 'C:\foo.csv.zip' recfm=n;
```

Comment: I guess this link will be helpful:
http://support.sas.com/kb/43/962.html
I have no experience in transfering files between FTP and local machine with sas myself, but the code example seems to have all steps you need

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you are missing is a data step that will read from one filename and write to the other, e.g.:

```
data _null_;
  infile rmt;
  file lcl;
  input;
  put _infile_;
run;
```

You will need to be much more specific about what you are trying to achieve with this part, though:

> 2. Scan all .zip folders for a specific name format

If you give some examples of the sorts of files you expect to find and which ones you would want to download, people may be able to advise.

Comment: when I try to use your advice I'm presented with an error stating "Invalid Open Mode". Any ideas?